# Mechanics: why is the work done by the weight of the object not taken into account in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

> A object of mass $0.3 \,kg$ is released from rest above a tank containing water. the object takes $0.8$ seconds to reach the water surface. there is no instantaneous change of speed when the particle enters the water. the depth of the water is $1.25\,m$. the water exerts a force resisting the particle's motion. the Work done against this resistance force is $1.2$ Joules. we need to find the speed of the object when it reaches the bottom of the tank.

here is my book's answer:

using work-energy relation:

work done by net force = change in mechanical energy

W.D by driving force - W.D against resistance = M.E (at the bottom) - M.E (at the surface)

$0- 1.2 =$ change in mechanical energy.

My question is why wasn't the weight of the object considered to find the work done by the net force?

Comment: The work done by graity is taken into account as change in potential energy, so it is on the right hand side of the equation. You can consider it as work and move it to the left hand side. Then you keep only KE change on the right hand side. In other words, you can use either conservation of energy or work-energy theorem.

Comment: See my answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/614865/difference-between-work-and-potential-energy-conceptually.  This elaborates on the above comment by @nasu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why wasn't the weight of the object considered to find
> the work done by the net force?

The weight is considered. It is in the work done by gravity.

The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

When the object reaches the top of the water its kinetic energy is

$$\frac{1}{2}mv_{T}^{2}$$

As it travels through the water two forces do work on it. Gravity and the resisting force of the water. The work done by gravity is positive $mgh$ where $mg$ is the weight, and the work done by the water is negative 1.2 J since its force is opposite the displacement of the object. Then the net work done on the object is

$$W_{net}=mgh-1.2$$

By the work energy theorem, that equals the change in kinetic energy of the object, or

$$mgh-1.2=\frac{1}{2}mv_{B}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv_{T}^{2}$$

Where subscripts $B$ and $T$ denote bottom and top, $h$ is the height of the water in the tank, and $mg$ is the weight of the object.

Which can be rewritten as

$$-1.2=\frac{1}{2}mv_{B}^{2}-\biggr(\frac{1}{2}mv_{T}^{2}+mgh\biggl)$$

Where

$$\frac{1}{2}mv_{B}^{2}$$

is the mechanical energy at the bottom, and

$$\biggr(\frac{1}{2}mv_{T}^{2}+mgh\biggl)$$

is the mechanical energy at the top.

Hope this helps.